How to keep Python pexpect shell open
I am trying to use pexpect to have a main processing loop that sends input to a number of other processes in order.
Code
pexpect_test.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 3
    processes = []
    for x in range(count):
        processes.append(pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', logfile=sys.stdout.buffer))
    print(f'Processes Created: {len(processes)}')

    inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for input in inputs:
        print(f'Processing input: {input}')
        for process in processes:
            line = f'python test.py {input}'
            print(f'Sending Line: {line}')
            process.sendline(line)
            print('reading')
            res = process.read()
            print(f'res: {res}')


test.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Process Started: {argv[1]} ')
    sleep(2)
    print(f'Process Complete: {argv[1]}')

Results
$ python pexpect_test.py 
Processes Created: 3
Processing input: a
Sending Line: python x.py a
python x.py a
reading
$ python x.py a
Process Started: a 
Process Complete: a
$ ^CTraceback (most recent call last):

It looks like the process ends up just waiting at the spawned shell so I either have to use control+c or let it timeout. How could I leave the shells running while returning the flow of logic back to the main script?
Simplified Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ps = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', logfile=sys.stdout.buffer)
    ps.sendline('python x.py 1 a')

    # Expect EOF
    ps.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    # - The child bash shell stays active and control does not go back to python code
    # - Will eventully timeout as expected and raise an exception
    # - Does correctly call python script and waits for the defined amount of time

    # Expect terminal character
    ps.expect_exact('$ ')
    # - The wait is skipped but the child shell does not remain active

    # Expect literal string printed in child process
    ps.expect_exact('Completed')
    # - Correctly spawns child thread and waits specified duration
    # - Return control back to script
    # - The requirement to add a print statement containing unique string is not desirable. 
    #  -There could be hundreds of different processes that need to be run and my group does not manage their code.

    # Expect the terminal character twice
    ps.expect('\$.*\$ ')
    # - For some reason this works exactly as I need it to. 

Notes:

Use subprocess.run(...): Not performant enough. The above sample code uses bin/bash as a placeholder, the actual command I need to run takes 2-3 seconds to initialize and I have a lot of inputs to process(10000+).


Read the documentation of pexpect.spawn.read(): If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. So process.read() will wait until the shell exits.

Use process.readline() if you just want to read one line. Or use process.expect() to read until a pattern, like the shell prompt.

@barmar I updated the code by adding process.expect('$') in place of read but the waiting doesn't happen. It just finishes instantly.

Remember that the argument to expect() is a regular expression, use expect_exact() to look for a simple string match.

expect() doesn't return the data that was read before the pattern was matched, just an index of which pattern was matched if you gave a list. The output in between is sent to the logfile.

I'm not an expect on using pexpect, I've just been googling it. I suggest you find a tutorial, it should help you code this.

i'd suggest you first learn how to work with one single spawned process before trying to interact with multiple spawned processes at the same time.

It seems I have tried each of the recommended approaches in the documentation so I must be missing something. I have updated the question with a simplified example and each attempt type.

I was able to determine what pattern to expect with the following approach:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ps = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', logfile=sys.stdout.buffer, timeout=7)
    ps.sendline('python x.py 1 a')
    try:
        ps.expect('something')
    except:
        print(ps.before)

Since the string passed to expect will match nothing, this will result in all output being in the before property which for my local machine was:
b'python x.py 1 a\r\n(base) \x1b]0;name@name-VirtualBox: ~/path/to/src\x07\x1b[01;32mname@name-VirtualBox\x1b[00m:\x1b[01;34m~/path/to/src\x1b[00m$ python x.py 1 a\r\nProcess 1 Started: a\r\nProcess 1 Completed: a\r\n(base) \x1b]0;name@name-VirtualBox: ~/path/to/src\x07\x1b[01;32mname@name-VirtualBox\x1b[00m:\x1b[01;34m~/path/to/src\x1b[00m$ '

This was different on the actual platform I need to use this for but the process will allow you to determine what you need to expect. For my local testing it was ps.expect('\$.*\$ ') but for the actual platform it was ps.expect('a-unique-string.*# ')

Sounds like you want pexpect.replwrap.REPLWrapper. The module contains convenience functions for python and bash REPLs. It knows how to work with the REPLs, their prompts and continuation prompts.
import os
import pexpect.replwrap

bash = pexpect.replwrap.bash()

out0 = bash.run_command('pwd')
assert out0.strip() == os.getcwd()

out1 = bash.run_command('echo $(( 1 + 2 ))')
assert out1.strip() == '3'

# send a command that is really two commands, one of which is multiline
out2 = bash.run_command('''echo some \\
                                silly
                           echo "test     "''')
assert out2.splitlines() == ['some silly', 'test     ']

# send an incomplete command that would otherwise hang indefinitely as the shell
# would print a continuation prompt, waiting for the rest of the command.
try:
    bash.run_command('echo test \\')
except ValueError as ex:
    assert 'Continuation prompt found - input was incomplete' in ex.args[0]
else:
    assert False
assert bash.run_command('echo shell still usable').strip() == 'shell still usable'

You can also pass a customised process to REPLWrapper and it will work with that too. In the following snippet, we start a process with a preset command prompt. This requires not running the bash profile or rc files, as these may change the prompt. However, doing this means you have a predictable prompt.
import pexpect.replwrap

proc = pexpect.spawn(
    '/bin/bash', ['--norc', '--noprofile'],
    env={
        'PS1': pexpect.replwrap.PEXPECT_PROMPT,
        'PS2': pexpect.replwrap.PEXPECT_CONTINUATION_PROMPT,
        'PROMPT_COMMAND': '',
        'PAGER': 'cat'
    },
    encoding='utf-8',
    echo=False,
)

bash = pexpect.replwrap.REPLWrapper(proc,
    orig_prompt=pexpect.replwrap.PEXPECT_PROMPT,
    # We already set prompt to the default that is expected, but we still
    # have to tell the wrapper what prompt to expect
    prompt_change=None,
    # no need to change prompt, but argument `prompt_change` is still expected
)

retval = bash.run_command('echo test')
assert retval.strip() == 'test'

The one caveat is that this example is susceptible to commands like env or printenv that print out the value of the command prompt (PS1). If you need to do this, then check out the fix that pexpect.replwrap._repl_sh applies to avoid this problem (it inserts non-printing characters into the prompt).
# If the user runs 'env', the value of PS1 will be in the output. To avoid
# replwrap seeing that as the next prompt, we'll embed the marker characters
# for invisible characters in the prompt; these show up when inspecting the
# environment variable, but not when bash displays the prompt.
ps1 = PEXPECT_PROMPT[:5] + non_printable_insert + PEXPECT_PROMPT[5:]
ps2 = PEXPECT_CONTINUATION_PROMPT[:5] + non_printable_insert + PEXPECT_CONTINUATION_PROMPT[5:]
prompt_change = u"PS1='{0}' PS2='{1}' PROMPT_COMMAND=''".format(ps1, ps2)


I have been unable to get the pexpect.replwrap.bash() approach to work with the remote command I need to run. It seems to work fine as long as the commands are run on the local machine but it looks like the prompt character is different on the remote machine I am working with and it just times out.

bash() is wrapper around REPLWrapper().  You can call REPLWrapper directly and customise the prompts it expects to whatever prompts your remote machine uses. Do you perhaps have a root shell? Most flavours of linux use # for a prompt rather than $, when the shell is running as the root user.

It does appear to be a root shell on the remote machine as it ends with #. I was able to get it to run the initial command but it seems I have to use run_command twice in a row otherwise the previous command won't execute.
I am using bash = pexpect.replwrap.REPLWrapper(' '.join(local_argv), '#', None) to create the object, then trying to use run_command for an array of commands.

@CogitoErgoSum I added a more robust solution that should work for any bash shell. It will function more like a non-interactive shell than an interactive one. So command histories and command aliases like ll (for ls -alF) will not be present.
